# Can eJabberd call an API if a roster contact does not exist?

Tags: ejabberd

Ejabberd newbie here. I hope this question makes sense.

We had a need to setup our own XMPP server so that customers on web and a Bria client can utilize it. I was able to get the basics up and running using ejabberd.

All users will be in the 'xmpp.exampledomain.com'

We also have a custom SMS gateway we built (which is really a server which can accept json APIs).

So what I am trying to accomplish:

1. Our platform would create a 'normal' xmpp user so the user can login to ejabberd.
2. This user can add roster contacts of other 'normal' xmpp users.
3. If this user wants to send messages via SMS, we would instruct them to add roster contacts (i assume) with the format 12125551234@sms.exampledomain.com. (adding the contact works currently)
4. If a user sends a message to this "SMS" contact, have ejabberd call our custom SMS gateway via a json API instead of attempting to deliver via normal xmpp.

Is this even possible?

For inbound from the SMS Gateway server, can call the ejabberd API send message function, so inbound is fairly easy.

I appreciate any suggestions

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want was called a "transport" in the old days of IRC, ICQ, AIM and MSN. They were programs that you installed next to ejabberd (or other Jabber servers). Example usage:

1. you download a transport for ICQ
2. configure it to have access to ICQ,
3. and then configure ejabberd to connect to that transport, and allow users to contact it at address icq.example.com.

There are very old tutorials for your curiosity:
https://www.ejabberd.im/tutorials-transports/index.html

I don't know if the old "SMS-Jabber transports" will work nowadays. Searching revelaed few results:

- https://www.jethrocarr.com/2013/06/03/smstoxmpp/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/jabbersms/
- https://www.jabber.cz/wiki/SMS_transport

Alternatively, as you mentioned you already have a SMS program, if you can get your hands on Erlang or Elixir, you can write an ejabberd module that registers at sms.example.com, and forwards XMPP messages as json API...

Comment: thank you very much. this helps!